# Why character # is null on argv

Tags: c, arguments

I was working with argv to store characters from the command line. And I just noted that if I input `#` I got a null instead of character `#`.  Why is this happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    printf("%c",argv[1][0]);
}
```

The code above works fine with any character, except `#` which returns Segmentation fault (core dumped) .

Comment: I think it's shell-specific.

Comment: That's your shell's comment character.

Comment: It's an OS question: OK with MSVC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `#` character denotes the start of a comment to the shell, so it never gets to your program.  As a result, `argv` only has one element, i.e. `argv[0]`, so accessing `argv[1]` is reading off the end of the array.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in this case manifests in a crash.

In order for the shell to pass this special character to your program, you need to quote it:

```
./myprogram "#"
```